# What does "new technology–based solutions" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, compounds

- New technology–based solutions

Does it mean

- Solutions that are based on new technology

or

- New solutions that are based on technology?

I think it can read as both.

Comment: What do you think a "based technology" is?

Comment: Did you mean to type based on technology?

Comment: People try to avoid writing sentences like that, because the meaning is ambiguous.

Comment: Solutions based on new technology.

Comment: Most of the time, it means nothing at all: _solutions_ is an piece of empty marketing-speak. (Yes, I know that's not the point of your question).

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct.

Some words like this are confusing in English.For example:

American history teacher

It has two meanings:

1- That teacher is from America and he teaches history.

2- That teacher is teaching America's history.

The meaning of these kinds of phrases depend on the sentence.

Comment: What if I say "new-technology-based solutions" then? Would it mean directly "solutions based on new technology" ?